# Как заставить синглтон на Qt отправлять сигналы?

Tags: qt, c++

Стоит задача из разных частей программы отправлять данные на вывод в гуй (а также иметь доступ к настройкам). Синглтон для этого лучшее решение. Но при использовании выплывает какая-то тупая ошибка при эмиссии сигнала, вроде сделал всё правильно, классически:

```
class QLogger : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    static const QLogger * instance();
    static void logger(const QString &str);

    static void setEnableLogging(bool stat);
    static inline bool isLoggingEnabled(){return self->enable;}

signals:
    void doSend(const QString &str);

private:
    static QChatLogger *self;
    QLogger(QObject * parent = 0);
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(QLogger)

    bool enable;  
};
//================================

QChatLogger *QChatLogger::self = 0;

QLogger::QLogger(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    self = this;
    self->enable = true;
}

const QLogger *QLogger::instance()
{
    static QLogger logger;
    return &logger;
}

void QLogger::logger(const QString &str)
{
    if (self->isLoggingEnabled ())
        emit self->doSend(str);
}

void QLogger::setEnableLogging(bool stat)
{
    self->enable = stat;
}
```

Ах да. Ошибка:

```
src/qlogger.cpp: In static member function 'static void QLogger::logger(const QString&)':
src/qlogger.cpp:19:50: error: passing 'const QLogger' as 'this' argument of 'void QLogger::doSend(const QString&)' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

**UPD:** Обновил код, он полностью рабочий. Happy Coding!

Comment: И все же не хватает блокировки одновременного доступа к свойству `enable`. Ведь этот логгер будет вызываться из разных потоков, а значит очень велика вероятность "гонок" при чтении-записи, что чревато неопределенным поведением логгера.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что

```
static const QLogger * instance();
```

Возвращает ptr на константный объект, так что его модификации будут недопустимы. Вообще в синглетоне достаточно иметь только один статический метод для доступа к экземпляру, а остальные методы должны быть не-статическими. Если преследуется цель не дать пользователю повод удалить синглетон, то можно возвращать вместо указателя ссылку на QLogger.

И еще: необходимо обеспечить потокобезопасность методов, т.к. собираетесь использовать его в многопоточном окружении.

Comment: Дак в С++0х все синглтоны потокобезопасны.

Comment: Что касается инициализации - да, верно. Но никто не гарантирует потокобезопасный доступ, например, к члену класса `enable` из разных потоков: пока один пишет, другой может читать, и тогда результат будет непредсказуем.

Comment: Вы правы, пробема была в модификаторе const. Сам не пойму зачем написал. Теперь вылезло несколько undefined reference to `QLogger::enable'. Везде где он используется - с объектом или без объекта...

Comment: Уберите "статику" от всех методов и членов класса, а функцию `QLogger::instance()` оставьте статической и ее содержимое не меняйте. Тогда работа всех методов заметно упростится.

Answer (score 2):

Заведите приватный указатель на объект класса внутри класса и работайте с ним, а не с QLogger::instance () внутри методов класса, должно помочь.
[Паттерн Singleton (Одиночка)](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/patterns/singleton.xml)

Comment: Внутри ли класса будет статический объект, или внутри функции - это в данном случае никакого значения не имеет, т.к. проблема именно в квалификаторе const.

Comment: Т.е. если я создам в классе QClass приватный указатель на объект класса QClass, никаких проблем не возникнет? Это безопасно? Какие могут быть подводные камни?

Comment: Вроде бы вполне, хотя тут @vladimir_ki прав и дело в const. А подводные камни - честно говоря не знаю, с++ основной язык, но я бы обратил внимание на потокобезопасность при создании этого статического объекта

Comment: При создании-то проблем с "гонками" не будет, т.к. это гарантировано стандартом, а вот при совместном доступе к данным уже созданного статического объекта - могут быть. Чтобы этого избежать, нужно принять спец. меры, например, критические секции, в методах синглетона.